# LBound and Ubound conflicts in case of array which has been assigned by the Range

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

**CODE**

```
    height = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob3.Columns(1))
    'MsgBox(height)
    ReDim dataArray(height - 2, 0) ' -1 for 0 index, -1 for the first row as header row, excluded
    str = ""
    dataArray = ob3.Range(ob3.Cells(2, 1),ob3.Cells(height, 1)).Value
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'MsgBox(LBound(DeletArr) & ":" & UBound(DeletArr))
    For i = LBound(DeletArr) To UBound(DeletArr)
        If Not d.exists(DeletArr(i)) Then
            d(DeletArr(i)) =  0
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(LBound(dataArray,1) & ":" & UBound(dataArray,1))
    For i = LBound(dataArray, 1)  To UBound(dataArray, 1) - 1

        If d.exists(dataArray(i, 1)) Then

            str = str & (i+1) & ":" & (i+1) & ","
            'ob3.Range(i & ":" & i).Delete

        Else
            'found = False
        End If

    Next
```

VBScript Array is 0 based. But why `LBound(dataArray,1)` is giving starting subscript is `1`,why not 0? `Ubound` is giving the number - against which i am bit confused is it the last subscript of the array or the size?

Thanks,

Comment: Merry Christmas! if you want array to be zero based, add `option base 0` :) Let me provide you a code to test out.

Comment: @bonCodigo Merry Christmas!to you,Hope you n your family enjoyed whole day!!

Comment: @bonCodigo Okay! i trust your word! but the number returned by Ubound(),is its last subscript or total number of elements in that array? please confirm also.Due to that concept my script causes data loses!!

Comment: can you show me exactly where do you have the issue of losing data? And if you refer to most of our sample codes that we have provided to you are using `Transpose` method to populate an array from Range object.

Comment: @bonCodigo I am basically educated in C,C++,java,oracle - in which platform I never had seen such scenarios! but its good luck Data lose helped me to know that factor! Now i need to really go to every script and need to check which are assigned by range and need  to set the loop not `lbound`as `0` but `1` and for `Ubound` not as `ubound-1` but as `Ubound`!!! Huuh GOD save me :-)

Comment: If you can set the code to navigate dynamically then you do not have to worry about what `LBound` each Array has. Unless you have a mixture of `1 based` and `0 based` array. You code is mainly depending on `Transpose` whch forces the involved arrays to be `1 based`. I **suggest you to add `Option Base 1` in your code. to make sure all your arrays are 1 based.** Code becomes manageable and to have sense of consistency. Yes C++, Java, C# are 0 based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the subscripts/indices of VBA arrays start at 0 (this is called the lower bound of the array) and run up to the number you specify in the Dim statement (this is called the upper bound of the array). If you would prefer your array index numbers to start at 1, include the following statement at the top of the module.

`Option Base 1`

[image]

However when an array is populated by `Range` object using the `Transpose` method, the array Lower bound set to 1 even you are on default `Zero baed` mode. So array becomes 1 based.

e.g. the following data is added using `Transpose` method.

```
Array(1) = "Hola"
Array(2) = "Bonjour"
Array(3) = "Hello"
Array(4) = "Wei"
```

Good thing is that this array `UBound` tells you number of elements (4) which = UBound. Unlike if it was zero based, then number of elements = Ubound + 1.

```
UBound(Array) --> 4
LBound(Array) --> 1
```

In current 1-based scenario, the Ubound refers to the total number of elements. So in such cases you need to amend your code to track data within the array's `LBound`, `UBound` properties to avoid data loss.

**And by the way, by adding `Option Base 0` doesn't stop array being dimentioned to 1 based by `Transpose` method.** Which invalids my first comment.

Comment: just to confirm one thing that `Arraylist` and Dic.keys and dic.items are `0` based right? I know that,still confirming the same!

Comment: what the syntax is to make an array as `0` based or `1` based? :-)

Comment: `Dictionary.keys` returns a `zero based` array, that's why when you do `Array = D.Keys` you get 0 based array. [Elements in this collection can be accessed using an integer index. Indexes in this collection are zero-based.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx)

Comment: If you want to **FORCE** all your arrays to be 1 based (best choice as per your scenario) then add `Option Base 1` after `Optoin Explicit` in the code module.

Comment: thanks for your huge explanations!! just one more information I am looking for is that - Can i write `ob4.Range("A1")` as `("1:1")`? please confirm. if it possible then I will be happy :-)

Comment: Yes you can define `Range("A1")` as `Cells(1,1)` both refers to the same destination and same object.

Comment: Range("1:1") is Range("A1")?