# What is the point/use of LBound in VBScript?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript

As far as I can establish there is no way to create a 1-based array (or any none 0 based array) in VBScript but it has a LBound function which should therefore always return 0.

So is this some kind of throw back from VB (as you can use "arrayName(1 to 10)") or is there a way that LBound could product a result other than 0 in VBScript (Classic ASP)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LBound() is part of VBScript because you could get a non-zero-based array from somewhere else via COM.

Comment: +1, but are the MSDN docs incorrect then? They state categorically that it will only ever return 0.

Comment: @RB. - here http://stackoverflow.com/q/14033478/603855 is a sample for LBound(array from excel) returning 1. The Docs could be improved by adding "for native VBScript arrays".