# What is the use of LBound function in QTP or VBScript? Even if we know any array dimension is zero

Tags: arrays, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

As I know, the value of `LBound()` for any dimension of array will be zero. So what is the use of it?

I did searching and found out below point, where `LBound()` found as useful but I didn't understand it.

I would appreciate if someone can explain it to me.

**For Example:** Use the `LBound` function with the `UBound` function to determine the size of an array.

**My question:** We can directly use `UBound + 1` to get size of an array. what is the mean of above statement?

Comment: VBScript arrays are always zero-based, so `LBound` essentially has no purpose there. I don't know about QTP.

Comment: What the description in your example means is that the size of an array can be calculated as `UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1`. That will always give you the correct size even if the array is not zero-based, while `UBound(arr) + 1` will only work correctly with zero-based arrays (like VBScript has).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15926973/603855

Comment: Many commands are from previous version of Basic. Take the `call` statement. It's purpose is to call assembler routines. In GWBasic it can't return a value (so you pass a parameter that you fill in from your assembler). So in VBScript where there is no need for it, it calls a function as a sub throwing away any return value (because assembler couldn't do it). VBScript has managed to get rid of `GoSub 200` which is legal VBA (for compatibility with older basics).